# How to use the data passed with ajax in the php script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am not sure how I should use the data passed along with an ajax call in the PHP script.
Specifically, here is the code for the ajax call:

```
if (node_selected!=0 & node_selected!=null){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php/fetch_sensors.php",
                    data: node_selected,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function( options ){
                        ...
                    }
                });
            }
```

'node_selected' is an integer variable.

And here is the PHP script (the fetch_sensors.php):

```
$query = "SELECT SensorID,Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN (SELECT SensorID FROM nodesensors WHERE NodeID=node_selected)";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die('query not made');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sensors[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($sensors);
```

If I replace 'NodeID=node_selected' with 'NodeID=2' (2 is just an example) everything works fine. So, I figure that I don't use correctly the 'node_selected'.
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: add in top of your php an echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>'; to see what we have .

Comment: @Danijel `'node_selected' is an integer variable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Jquery:

```
 if (node_selected!=0 && node_selected!=null){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/fetch_sensors.php",
                data: {myNode: node_selected}, //like this
                dataType:'json',
                success: function( options ){
                    ...
                }
            });
  }
```

#### PHP:

```
$myNode = mysql_escape_string($_POST["myNode"]);
$query = "SELECT SensorID,Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN ";
$query.= "(SELECT SensorID FROM nodesensors WHERE NodeID= '".$myNode."')";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die('query not made');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $sensors[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($sensors);
```

Comment: +1 Although you should either cast to `int` if you don't quote the value in the query or use a string escape function and quote it. Now your query can break.

Comment: You are right @jeroen, i post my answer under the assumtion that `SensorID` is an `int` field, but it could be alphanumeric...editing..

Comment: Yep, it works, thanks a lot. But why do I have to pass the data like that?? Why "data: node_selected" isn't enough??

Comment: According to jquery documentation: `data
Type: PlainObject or String or Array
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).` ...source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3):

You have to send a key/value pair. You are only sending a value.

If you want to receive `$_POST['NodeID']` in php then the easiest way in jQuery AJAX is to create an object using the same key

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/fetch_sensors.php",
    data: {
        NodeID: node_selected
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (options) {...
    }
});
```

The easiest way to think of it is the object keys are the same as using `name` in a form control. The processing of most ajax at server is identical to processing of forms

Answer (score 1):

Give your data a key, so you can fetch is in php via `$_POST` global:

```
//js
data: {node_selected: node_selected},

//php
$query = "SELECT SensorID,Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN (SELECT SensorID FROM nodesensors WHERE NodeID=" . $_POST['node_selected'] . ")";
```